# Raspberry Pi connecting to Wifi but not ethernet

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, ethernet

I am trying to SSH into a Raspberry Pi 3B+ using ethernet, but it says: **No route to Host**. Pinging the IP doesn't work either, and raspberrypi.local doesn't seem to be resolved by mDNS.

When I tried using Wifi to connect to it instead, it worked just fine.

I have been able to SSH into the raspberry pi using WiFi and have checked the IP on eth0 for the RPi using IP addr:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:22:f4:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.189.13/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe22:f45a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:77:a1:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.177/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::99d8:11a3:edc1:8496/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

I am not sure how the second `169.254.189.13` came into the picture.

I have manually set my Ubuntu PC's IP to 192.168.0.10 to stay in the same subnet, but it just cannot ping. The RPi cannot ping Ubuntu either using the address on the ethernet port.

I have tried SSH-ing to a Raspberry Pi 3B and that works just fine.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Does it work with an unmodified fresh flashed [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)?

Comment: Have you set ```country=GB``` (or your country code) in wpa_supplicant.conf? Can you confirm your AP is NOT using WEP? Do you have a weedy power supply?

Comment: @Dougie I can connect to the wifi just fine, the trouble is with ethernet.

Comment: @Ingo An unmodified Raspbian Stretch Full (Including the GUI and recommended components)

Comment: Then swap the cat5 cable, swap the RPi power supply, check you aren't trying to set the same IP address on both interfaces.

Comment: You have a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) `169.254.189.13/16` **and** a private address `192.168.0.100/24`. This is never set by a default Raspbian image. So please use an unmodified one.

Comment: You give the Ubuntu PC a static ip address `192.168.0.10` and you configure **eth0** on the RasPi also with a static ip address `192.168.0.100`, can you confirm this? Is the wired connection between RasPi and PC point to point, or are there other devices present, e.g. using a switch?

Comment: Your question bumped up again and will do it year for year. Do you have solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a DHCP or a DNS server on your ethernet port? That would likely cause problems with existing DHCP providers, and could force your PI into a different IP range than all other devices.

That would render it unreachable by others, and unable to reach other devices.

mDNS is not needed if you know your IPs. All a DNS does for you is translate host-names or domains into IPs so your computer knows what IP to talk to.